# best way to handle html input sanitization in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, xss

What is the best way to handle the input sanitation using jquery?

how to sanitize the input in the example shown below?

http://watchitlater.com/blog/2011/10/cross-site-scripting-vulnerability-with-javascript-and-jquery/

Comment: In the example from your blog post, is having a script tag print out as text something that is required or would you rather remove the script tag all together from the user input?